# How to return object or string value with arcpy.SetParameter

Tags: python, arcmap, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

I am creating a geoprocessing tool in ArcMap 10.5.1. I have the following code:

```py
import arcpy
event_data = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
event_data_id = arcpy.SetParameter(1, event_data)
event_data_pc = arcpy.SetParameter(2, event_data)
```

- `event_data` is the feature class.
- `event_data_id` is the unique id field of the event_data.  This variable is set in the geoprocessing tool interface.
- `event_data_pc` is the postal code field of the event_data.  This variable is set in the geoprocessing tool interface.

However, when I run:

```py
arcpy.AddMessage(str(type(event_data_id)) + ", " + str(type(event_data_pc)))
```

I get `None, None`.

What happens to these objects?  Why are they not being passed to the `event_data_id` and `event_data_pc` variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arcpy.SetParameter()` function does not return anything and it is used to pass an object to a parameter of the Geoprocessing Tool which direction is Output. When you say

> This variable is set in the geoprocessing tool interface

do you mean is set as an input parameter? I believe you want to read those parameters instead of setting them. You could try:

```py
event_data_id = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
event_data_pc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
arcpy.AddMessage("{}, {}".format(event_data_id, event_data_pc))
```

Note that I changed your `arcpy.AddMessage()` statement, assuming you want to print the id field and postal code field names.

---

If you rather want to get the values for those fields in the Feature Class passed to the tool and these values are not being passed directly as parameters, you'd have to parse the Feature class and get those values.

Comment: Oh man!  Classic overthinking this problem.  Yes, you are correct @Marcelo Villa.   I didn't need to use SetParameter at all.  I was just confusing the the configuration of the input parameters (i.e., dependencies on the feature class) with the arcpy function.  Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help.